# How can I create a blob index field correctly with Solr 5?

Tags: java, oracle, solr, blob

I think the title of my question explains much of what I need. I am using the [Data Importer Handler](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) of Apache SOLR 5. I configured my `solrconfig.xml`, `schema.xml` and `data-config.xml`. It's working for now.

However, I need to add one more field. An **Oracle Blob field**. First, let me show my configurations:

**data-config.xml**

```
<dataConfig>

    <!-- Datasource -->
    <dataSource name="myDS" 
                setReadOnly="true" 
                driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" 
                url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//server.example.com:1521/service_name" 
                user="user" 
                password="pass"/>

    <document name="products">
        <entity name="product"
                dataSource="myDS" 
                query="select * from products"
                pk="id"
                processor="SqlEntityProcessor">
            <field column="id" name="id" />
            <field column="name" name="name" />
            <field column="price" name="price" />
            <field column="store" name="store" />
            <!-- I've added this blob field -->
            <field column="picture" name="picture" />
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

**solrconfig.xml**

```
  <requestHandler name="/products" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
      <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
      </lst>
  </requestHandler>

  <!-- JDBCs -->
  <lib dir="../../../lib" />
```

**My fields in schema.xml**

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="_text" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="price" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<!-- BLOB field -->
<field name="picture" type="binary" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<copyField source="*" dest="_text"/>
<!-- ommited solr default fields -->
```

Now, when I start a full-importer, SOLR only indexes some records. This is the output after SOLR finish the importing:

```
Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 64 documents. Deleted 0 documents. (Duration: 04s)
Requests: 1 (0/s), Fetched: 1369 (342/s), Skipped: 0, Processed: 64 (16/s)
Started: less than a minute ago
```

As you can see, I have 1369 records, **but SOLR only index 64 documents**. If I remove the field `picture` from schema or, set `index` and `stored` attributes to `false`, SOLR import all documents.

I opened the SOLR log, and found this error when importing the blob field:

```
3436212 [Thread-19] WARN  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter  – Error creating document : SolrInputDocument(fields: [name=PRODUCTNAME, price=PRICE, store=STORE, picture=oracle.sql.BLOB@4130607a, _version_=1497915495941144576])
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=<ID>] Error adding field 'picture'='oracle.sql.BLOB@4130607a' msg=Illegal character .
    at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:176)
    at org.apache.solr.update.AddUpdateCommand.getLuceneDocument(AddUpdateCommand.java:78)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc0(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:240)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:166)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:69)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:51)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:931)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:697)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter.upload(SolrWriter.java:71)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler$1.upload(DataImportHandler.java:263)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:511)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:415)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:330)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:232)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:416)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:480)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:461)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character .
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.Base64.base64toInt(Base64.java:150)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.Base64.base64ToByteArray(Base64.java:117)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.BinaryField.createField(BinaryField.java:89)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType.createFields(FieldType.java:305)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.addField(DocumentBuilder.java:48)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:123)
    ... 18 more
```

I checked querying directly against database, and it's working fine. I am using SOLR 5, ojdbc7 and Java 8. How can I use the binary field correctly in SOLR?

---

### Update

I've changed the properties of `picture` in `schema.xml` setting `indexed=false`. This way:

```
<!-- BLOB field -->
<field name="picture" type="binary" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
```

Then, I restarted SOLR, reloaded my core, and did a Full-Import again. No success and same exception. The same 64 documents that I described above was imported and **the field picture does not appear in JSON respons**e. The query I execute is:

```
/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true
```

Comment: Can I ask why you're *indexing* the BLOB instead of merely storing it? You're not going to be searching it, are you - just displaying it with search results? I'm wondering if your index will work if you set `indexed="false"` for that field.

Comment: Because I tried everything to make this work. I've set `index = false`, `stored = false` and any other combination. Dind't work. Same exception.

Comment: Well you definitely don't want `stored="false"`. It might be worth trying to base64 encode the image.